# I have the JSON. How can I fetch student_id, first_name, and second_name?

Tags: swift3

This is JSON I parsed from a URL. Now I want `student_id`, `first_name`, and `second_name` from this JSON. How can i get that?

```
[{
    "timestamp": "2017-06-29 05:37:23",
    "student_id": "6",
    "first_name": "SACHIN",
    "second_name": "SINGH",
    "sex": "male",
    "student_course": "TECH-NON-TECH",
    "email_id": "sachinsinghchahar9058841073@gmail.com",
    "password": "kbmss@10002",
    "phone": "8879505608",
    "login_id": "kbmss",
    "status": "2",
    "roll_no": "",
    "payment": "cash",
    "amount_description": "cash",
    "amount": "8500",
    "refrence_id": "",
    "child_id": "0",
    "plan": "advance",
    "valid_upto": "2017-12-14"
}]
```

Comment: Tip: To make your code format nicely, add 4 spaces to the left of each line - this is called Markdown and you can learn more by a quick Web search.

Comment: Also, this site has some great guidance on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - there's more documentation on other related subjects too. Reading this and following the guidance greatly increases your chance of an answer. e.g. one of the issues with your question is that it doesn't have a code example of what you've tried. That means it's too broad or not enough information for someone to help. However, showing what you've done makes it easier for someone to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Access the properties of the object which holds your JSON with either `.` or `[]` notation and get what you need. In your case it is technically `JSONvar[0].student_id` for example

Answer (score 0):

```
switch response.result{
    case .success(let data) :
    let json = JSON(data)
```

For more explanation you can go to this link.

> [How to get values of an array of dictionary from alamofire response using swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154618/how-to-get-values-of-an-array-of-dictionary-from-alamofire-response-using-swift3/51184193#51184193)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20212551)

Comment: @petezurich Currently it i correct answer right? Then its too bad an action that you downvoted my answer.

Comment: @FaheemRahman Link only answers get downvoted quickly. It probably wasn't the reviewer above who downvoted it. I see you've edited the answer to contain the code. That's a good start and will prevent it from getting deleted, but maybe adding a bit of an explanation about why this works will help, and will probably turn those downvotes to upvotes!